# один метод для проверки вводимых значений для каждого textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, коллекции, textbox

как создать один метод для проверки вводимых значений для каждого из 6 textbox-ов. Например, при вводе символов в поле int id - во время работы программы появлялось уведомление о невозможности символьного ввода ввода, аналогично с полем double, при вводе пустой строчки - тоже уведомление с просьбой заполнить. При этом все уведомления должны добавляться в список и выводиться в консоль.
Cсылка на проект `https://pastebin.com/JXK6NQdz`.

```
 private List<String> errList = new List<String>();

    private void validator(TextBox tb) {


            if (tb.Name.Contains("Int")) {
                int n;
                if (!int.TryParse(tb.Text, out n))
                {
                    string s1 = "Не число! Пожалуйста, введите число!";
                    errList.Add(s1);
                    MessageBox.Show(s1, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }

            }
            else if (tb.Name.Contains("Double")){
            double n;
            if (!double.TryParse(tb.Text, out n))  {
                string s2 = "Не число! Пожалуйста, введите число!";
                errList.Add(s2);
                MessageBox.Show(s2, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
        else { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если абстрагироваться от WinForms, то можно поступить следующим способом:

- Создадим универсальный метод конвертации:

  ```
  private static T Check<T>(string value, string msg)
  {
      var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
      if (converter.IsValid(value))
      {
          return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(value);
      }
      Console.WriteLine(msg);
      return default(T);
  }
  ```

Так, как у меня консольный проект, то я в просто вывожу сообщение об ошибке в консоль (`Console.WriteLine(msg);`), ну и `static` по этой же причине.
Вызов будет примерно следующим:

```
var result = Check<int>("value", "Не число!");
```

- Далее мы можем сделать словарь, который будет содержать текст ошибки, название вашей кнопки и т.д.:

  ```
  public static Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>> ErrDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>>
  {
      ["int"] = value => Check<int>(value, "Не является числом!"),
      ["double"] = value => Check<double>(value, "Не является числом с плавающей запятой!")
  };
  ```

Вызов тогда получим примерно следующий:

```
var result = ErrDictionary["int"]("value");
```

Но тут есть одно но - `result` будет иметь тип `object`, ибо стандартный словарь не дает использовать Generic без лишнего кода.